# Attempting to make a POST call from a Google App Script

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, httprequest

I am trying to trigger a POST call as a webhook to trigger a workflow in an external system from Google Sheets using Google App Script

The logic is fine, I have tested that the script will trigger as I want when a cell in column 6 is edited. The issue is I cannot get the call to my webhook URL to be sent

In my code below I have brought it back to the example Google have in their docs just to try and get it working before I add the data I actually want. Any pointers would be appreciated. It is going to be something stupid...I have been looking at it too long and have dug into too many resources.

```
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  if (col == 6){

    var data = {
      'name': 'Bob Smith',
      'age': 35,
      'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
    };
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
    };
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://webhook.site/26d7bc1e-8d40-4249-bbf4-f7360ae26424', options);

  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: About ``I cannot get the call to my webhook URL to be sent``, can I ask you about the error message when ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()`` is run? And also can I ask you about the specification of the webhook?

Comment: @Tanaike Wow. This is my first time using Google Scripts and I had looked for the errors but couldn't find them! I did a search and now I see where to get them! The error is:

"You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request at onEdit(cellListen:19)"

At the moment I am just trying to catch the trigger at the webhook.site URL but for my integration, I will be catching it with Cloud Elements in order to manipulate the data and add in other data before forming an API call to another platform.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you run the script by OnEdit event trigger, how about using the installable trigger? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable I thought that when the simple trigger is used for your situation, such error might occur.

Comment: Amazing! I added an installable trigger and success! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you can do, can you post the answer and accept it? By this, users can see your question as the resolved question.

Comment: @Tanaike Sure! I think you commented rather than answered though so I can't check it as the correct answer. If you leave the answer I will mark it as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. And I appreciate your concern. I posted an answer by adding information. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

When the script is run by OnEdit event trigger of `onEdit(), this is the simple trigger. In this case, when the methods for requiring to authorize are included in the script, suth error occurs. In your case, it's`UrlFetchApp.fetch()``.

#### Solution:

In order to avoid this error, please use the installable trigger. When you use the installable trigger, please modify the function name from `onEdit()` to other name like `sample()`. By this, running 2 times of the script can be prevented.

#### Note:

- In your case, if `onEdit()` is installed as the installable trigger of OnEdit trigger, `onEdit()` which is run as the simple trigger occurs an error in your question. And then, `onEdit()` which is run as the installable trigger works. So it looks like that the script is run 1 time.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)

  - In this report, when `onEdit()` is installed as the installable trigger, it shows that `onEdit()`, which is run as the simple trigger, and `onEdit()`, which is run as the installable trigger, are run with the asynchronous processing.